# Android Room Kotlin - Query in background thread - return value problem

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have converted a sample program from Java/SQLite to Kotlin/Room.

I am struggling to implement queries with return values in a background thread.

This has been asked but I could not get it to work.
I have read answers to similar questions but some are deprecated, or some solutions seem complex for something that should be trivial.

I am really stumped in coming up with a simple solution when I need to use the return value of the query.

(Everything works as it should if I force doing queries in the main thread with allowMainThreadQueries())

This is one of the functions that I would like to have do the query in a background thread:

```
fun getCrimes(): List<Crime> {
    val crimes = crimesDAO.getAllCrimes() as ArrayList<Crime>
    return crimes
}
```

I can call the function like follows and it works but it would mean that I need to add Async calls throughout other classes and it does not seem elegant:

```
AsyncTask.execute {
    mCrimes = getCrimes() as ArrayList<Crime>
}
```

**==> I would like to modify getCrimes itself to have it run the query in the background, like:** (incorrect code follows)

```
fun getCrimes(): List<Crime> {
    var crimes: ArrayList<Crime>

    AsyncTask.execute {
        crimes = crimesDAO.getAllCrimes() as ArrayList<Crime>
    }

    return crimes // This is wrong as crimes in not initialized
}
```

I looked into kotlin coroutines, Live Data and rxjava but could not find a simple way around this.

### Background info:

This is the data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "crimes_table")
class Crime {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="id")
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name="uuid")
    @TypeConverters(UUIDConverter::class)
    var mId: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()

    @ColumnInfo(name="title")
    var mTitle: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="date")
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
    var mDate: Date? = Date()

    @ColumnInfo(name="solved")
    var mSolved: Boolean = false
}
```

This is the DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CrimesListDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM crimes_table")
    fun getAllCrimes(): List<Crime>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM crimes_table WHERE uuid = :uuidString LIMIT 1")
    fun getOneCrime(uuidString: String): Crime

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertCrime(crime: Crime)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun updateCrime(crime: Crime)

    @Delete
    fun deleteCrime(crime: Crime)
}
```

This is the DatabaseApp class:

```
@Database(entities = [(Crime::class)], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun crimesListDAO(): CrimesListDAO
}
```

This is how I instantiate the database:

```
class ApplicationContextProvider : Application() {
    ...
    companion object {
        var database: AppDatabase? = null
    ...
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ApplicationContextProvider.database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "crimeBase.db").build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Step One

Turn your blocking function

```
fun getCrimes() = crimesDAO.getAllCrimes() as List<Crime>
```

into a suspending one:

```
suspend fun getCrimes() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    crimesDAO.getAllCrimes() as List<Crime>
}
```

#### Step Two

In order to call a suspendable function you must first launch a coroutine:

```
override fun onSomeEvent() {
    (context as LifecycleOwner).lifecycleScope.launch {
        val crimes = getCrimes()
        // work with crimes
    }
}
```

This works as long as your `context` is not a legacy activity/fragment class. Modern classes, such as `AppCompatActivity`, implement `LifecycleOwner`.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I figured out last night and posted the solution

Comment: In particular, I wanted to avoid having to call all the DAO functions from different fragments using the ugly 
    (context as CoroutineScope).launch {
        val crimes = getCrimes() }  - This is not the only function: this is 1 example 5 functions called from 2 fragments. I wanted a more elegant and contained solution. And the solution I proposed below works perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: My answer is wrong. (thanks Marko)
It does start another background thread, BUT it still blocks the UI Thread.
So this circumvents Room protection to not make calls in UI thread, but it defeats the purpose.

I used the below code to confirm that I was generating a new thread but blocking the caller thread anyway:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    exampleBlockingDispatcher()
}

suspend fun printlnDelayed(message: String) {
    delay(2000)
    println(message)
}

// Running on another thread but still blocking the main thread
fun exampleBlockingDispatcher(){
    runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
        println("one - from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        printlnDelayed("two - from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    // Outside of runBlocking to show that it's running in the blocked main thread
    println("three - from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    // It still runs only after the runBlocking is fully executed.
}
```

---

Original Answer:

After many hours I figured it out (edit: I wish). The correct way to call the DAO methods using coroutines in a background thread and be able to have a value returned is:

```
fun getCrimes(): ArrayList<Crime> = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val result = async { crimesDAO.getAllCrimes() }.await()
    return@runBlocking result as ArrayList<Crime>
}
```

Read a lot of code & tutorials but by far the best I recommend on coroutines is this one:

https://resocoder.com/2018/10/06/kotlin-coroutines-tutorial-stable-version-async-await-withcontext-launch/

It has a lot of examples with simple code that helps to grasp details and see / try them in action.

Comment: This example is entirely wrong. `runBlocking` annihilates the effect of `async`. Plus, you use the `async-await` antipattern instead of `withContext` (but fixing just that won't save you).

Comment: No. It does not because it blocks the next thread not the UI thread. It works perfectly fine. You are missing (Dispatchers.Default). It blocks, yes, but the next background thread

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Coroutine context includes a coroutine dispatcher (see CoroutineDispatcher) that determines what thread or threads the corresponding coroutine uses for its execution. Coroutine dispatcher can confine coroutine execution to a specific thread, dispatch it to a thread pool, or let it run unconfined.

Comment: Once you properly learn coroutines you'll see that your proposal is almost like claiming you invented perpetual motion. You have `fun getCrimes()`: it's not a `suspend fun`. Therefore it will block its calling thread until it comes up with its return value. To convince yourself, write this: `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { GlobalScope.async { Thread.sleep(100_000) }.await() }` inside a GUI callback of your choice. I suggest `Activity.onCreate()`. If your claim is correct, your application will remain responsive and the above line of code will take almost no time to run.

Comment: BTW I see that you call the top-level `async` function. It is deprecated in the experimental API and you won't be able to migrate your code to the stable API if you don't fix this.

Comment: Pls run this code and you will see that the function is using a worker thread not the main thread:                                  
suspend fun calculateHardThings(startNum: Int): Int {
    delay(2000)
    return startNum * 10
}

fun exampleSolution() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val result = async { calculateHardThings(10) }.await()
    println("async/await result = $result - ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}

Comment: Please tell me a better way to do this WITHOUT having to change all function calls on different classes from 1 line to multiple lines just to be able to launch a process in a worker thread and have it return a result

Comment: You are indeed right that the function runs on another thread. Sadly for you, your calling thread blocks waiting for that other thread to be done. It's just like `future.get()` in plain old Java.

Comment: Nope, you can't use coroutines without launching them, and the Android callback is not already in a coroutine. It's equivalent to the requirement to start a thread in plain Java. There's a very good article capturing the essence of your frustration with Kotlin's stackless coroutines: [What Color is Your Function?](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/)

Comment: @Will: you realizing slowly that you were wrong the whole time is my professional developer career in a nutshell :)

Comment: @rTECH - ;-) Ha, you are right. But I guess trying things out is how you actually learn, right?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the guidance with your question! Steered me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Using Room all requests to the database by default have to be made in background thread. Why not use coroutines?
You could use it with something like this:

```
suspend fun retrieveCrimes(): List<Crime> {
    return async {
        delay(5000)
        1
    }.await()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is clear I am not that familiar with coroutines. How would you go about and call it and then retrieving the value ? I tried implementing it but I got: "Suspend function 'retrieveCrimes' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Comment: 1. This uses the `async-await` antipattern instead of `withContext`. 2. It uses the outdated experimental API. `async` is no longer a top-level function. 3. It doesn't explain that you must launch a coroutine to be able to call a `suspend fun`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with AsyncTask, but it seems like you're returning the variable 'crime' even before the background task actually finished fetching the data and assigns the value to it.

You need to return the crimes (the result of the DB query) after AsyncTask completed fetching the data. You're returning the crimes even before the background is completed because you put the return statement right after the execute() call.

If you want to use AsyncTask, you need to implement the callbacks (i.e. onPostExecute(), doInBackground(), etc. ). You can return your result data from the DB(in this case, crimes) from the doInBackground() callback.

I personally prefer using RxJava with Room database rather than AsyncTask because it makes your code cleaner and straightforward :)

Comment: Thank a lot. Yes you are right, that is the problem I am trying to overcome. Will explore RxJava more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I know is to use coroutines. Yo can use something like this:

```
//For example fron the activity's onCreate method:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    launch(UI){
        ....
        val allCrimes = bg{
            crimesDAO.getAllCrimes()
        }.await()
        //do something with allCrimes (as a List<Crime>)
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. How exactly can I access "allCrimes" and perhaps return the array to the calling fun (which is another fragments function)

Comment: Here allCrimes will be a List<Crime>. You can access it as you do regularly with any other variable.

Comment: 1. This doesn't compile. `bg` is an unknown symbol. 2. It uses the `async-await` antipattern instead of `withContext`. 3. It uses the outdated experimental API. `launch` is not a top-level function, `UI` got renamed to `Main`, and you shouldn't even have to specify it explicitly if you implement it the proper way by making your activity become a `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: I'm using anko "import org.jetbrains.anko.coroutines.experimental.bg" and It works perfectly fine. Maybe I'm outdated... why is this use of async-await an antipattern? I'm researching a bit right now :) Thanks

Comment: I see, you're combining Anko with coroutines. That's not necessary since the main Kotlin API has an equivalent: `async(Default) { ... }` About the async-await thing, just as the Anko function name states, is about letting a computation run in the background, concurrent to our code. But writing `await` right after `async` means that none of our computation will happen until the other task is done. You need such a thing only to transfer the execution to another thread. For that, Kotlin offers `withContext(Default) { ...}` which is also more efficient because it reuses the current coroutine.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik where can I find a guide to use latest "no experimental" coroutines? I've searched in my project build.gradle files but I have no other dependencies configured than anko ones. In all my .kt files the imports begins with kotlinx.coroutines.experimental. Where are coroutines coming from if I'm not adding them as dependencies? where are coroutines packed? If it is too much for a comment just tell me and I will formulate a new question.

Comment: Probably you have a transitive dependency through Anko. Otherwise it would be kotlinx-coroutines-android. As I write this, the version is 0.30.3-eap13. But you must also upgrade IDEA to an EAP version so you get Kotlin 1.3 support, and upgrade the version of Kotlin in the gradle build.. It will be ironed out in a couple of weeks when the official release happens.